# Writing object in text file

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write an object(Transaction) in text file.
The Transaction  object contains card no, amount, date.
I need to write the object in text file as below with some gaps.

```
 Card no      Amount      Date

  12335       900.00     29/09/2010
```

I have used ObjectOutputStream to write the object in  the file. But I couldn't able to give the gaps in this case.

How to write the transaction object in a file with some gaps, so that it can be aligned with header?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where's the code for what you've attempted?

Comment: You can't serialise an object in this way, you need to write the "text" represented by the text to a text file, using maybe something like `String#format`

Comment: Deserialization will give you the same object you serialized. Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653374/whats-the-difference-between-serialization-and-simply-store-the-object-on-disk

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concerned about gaps in ObjectOutputStream. Its mainly used for writing to file and recreating objects back. If you want to use it to write it to a file in a human readable format suggest you to use normal file output stream and not object output stream.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. In normal file output stream how to provide gaps and write it in a file at single stretch?

Comment: @Ramya hope this link helps http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm

Comment: Using filewriter I was able to write the object with out gaps. How to specify the position to write the object in this position.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your Transaction object looks like.  But this should provide some clues.  Note System.out.printf().   You can substitute your own output streams.  I threw in extra stuff on the Calendar object just so you can get a sense of it...

```
private class Transaction {
    public int cardno;
    public BigDecimal amt;
    public Date someDate;
}

public void zz2() {
    Transaction t = new Transaction();
    t.cardno = 12335;
    t.amt = new BigDecimal("900.00");

    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.set( Calendar.YEAR,        2013 );
    cal.set( Calendar.MONTH,       9);  // zero offset so 9 = Oct              
    cal.set( Calendar.DATE,        1 ); // NOT zero offset...                  
    cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (15) );  // 3PM                             
    cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE,      30 );
    cal.set( Calendar.SECOND,      44 );
    cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 700 );

    t.someDate = cal.getTime();

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    String s = df.format(t.someDate);

    System.out.println("Card no      Amount      Date");
    System.out.printf ("%6d %12s   %10s\n",
                      t.cardno,
                      t.amt,
                      s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but have you tried using tabs (escaped in a string to "\t") in the positions you need the gaps?

```
System.out.println("Card no\tAmount\tDate");
```

Similarily for the println statement where you're outputting the values.